# React search with more than one parameters

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

I have a search bar with two input fields being combined. The first input is "desc" and the second one is "location". Every time I try to use it, they always take the "desc" input value, even though I'm filling in "location" input field too. When I try to use the second input field, the "location" input value always got `undefined`.

You can find my code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [find, setFind] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getJobsAPI();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  },[])

  const getJobsAPI = () => {
    axios.get(`https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json`)
      .then((res) => {
        setJobs(res.data)
      })
  }

  const findJobsAPI = async (desc, location) => {
    await axios.get(`https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${desc}&location=${location}`)
    .then((res) => {
      setJobs(res.data)
    })
  }


  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFind(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    findJobsAPI(find);
    setFind("");
    e.target.reset();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mx-6 my-4">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
            <div>
              <p>Job Description</p>
              <input
                className="py-0.5 px-2 mr-3 border-gray-300 border-2"
                placeholder="Filter by title, benefits, companies, expertise"
                name="desc"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Location</p>
              <input
                className="py-0.5 px-2 mr-3 border-gray-300 border-2"
                placeholder="Filter by city, state, zip code or country"
                name="location"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label className="font-semibold ml-2">Full Time Only</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit" className="text-white font-semibold rounded bg-gray-500 py-2 px-3 hover:bg-gray-800 hover:transition duration-300 ease-in-out">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div>
          <p className="text-black font-semibold text-3xl">Job List</p>
        </div>
        {jobs.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="border-t-2">
            <div className="my-3">
              <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
                <Link to={`/positions/${item.id}`}>
                  <p className="text-primary-blue font-bold text-xl hover:text-blue-700 hover:transition duration-300 ease-in-out">{item.title}</p>
                </Link>
                <p>{item.location}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
                <p className="text-gray-500">{item.company} - <b className="text-primary-green">{item.type}</b></p>
                <p>{item.created_at}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>

  )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: You are calling `findJobsAPI(find);` with just one parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have two fields, you only use one event handler for them and both of these fields update the same state. Instead of using one state (`find`) for the two fields, you could use two states (`location` and `description`) and update them on input change. In `findJobsAPI` you don't need to provide any arguments as the function has access to these values.

```js
function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([]);
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = React.useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  // ...

  const findJobsAPI = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const URL = encodeURIComponent(
      `https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${description}&location=${location}`
    );
    fetch(`https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=${URL}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setJobs(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    // you should handle errors!
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    findJobsAPI();
    setDescription('');
    setLocation('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>
          Job Description
          <input
            placeholder="Filter by title, benefits, companies, expertise"
            name="desc"
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            value={description}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Location
          <input
            placeholder="Filter by city, state, zip code or country"
            name="location"
            onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
            value={location}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ loading, description, location }, null, 2)}</pre>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ jobs }, null, 2)}</pre>
      {/* ... */}
    </form>
    //  ...
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
button,
input {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.325rem 0.5rem;
}
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i just try your code, it's works but the problem is when i try to search in the "location" input field, the data won't update, do u have some advice for this?

Comment: It seems to be updating the location as well for me. What do you mean by _the data won't update_? The data fetched from GitHub or the field's value?

Comment: Oh, I see, you meant the fetched data. That's because the URL you pass to `allorigins.win` should be encoded if it contains a query string. Check the snippet above, it should work as expected now. I'm using fetch instead of axios above as I didn't want to import anything here.

Comment: oh okay i got it, thank you so much for your help :D